# Why does git-flow not delete remote *release* branches (when finished)?

Tags: git, git-flow

Referring to "out of the box" developer workflow via git-flow (version 0.4.2-pre).

For a release, we perform these steps:

```
git flow release start 4.2.3
maven release:prepare release:perform
git flow release finish 4.2.3
```

Now, after the `release finish` command, `git flow` has deleted the local branch `release/4.2.3` (after merging into `master` and back merging into `develop`.

My question is: why isn't the remote branch `release/4.2.3` also deleted? (After all, we have the `tag` for `4.2.3`)

Even, going back a step, why was branch `release/4.2.3` pushed in the first place?

Or are we doing something wrong (?)

Comment: You need to find out why the release branch was pushed. By default, it is local only and shouldn't even exist on the remote.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Perhaps it was `mvn release` which pushed it? If so, are we doing things correctly with regards to that?

Comment: I have found that the Maven Release plugin does not work well with the git flow tools. I think you're right, it probably was the Maven Release plugin that pushed the branch as part of the release. Check out these links for more info and some alternatives: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/maven-git-flow-plugin-for-better-releases/ and https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow

Comment: I guess I can go and delete the release branches manually. Last question - we do maven release from the release/4.2.3 branch, right? never from master?

Comment: Yes, the Maven release needs to be made from the release branch. Just be careful with the version numbers - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that the Maven Release plugin does not work well with the git flow tools. There are several issues with it, e.g. it checks out a full copy of the repo in a temp directory, its version number updates don't work well with the Git Flow workflow, etc. One of the main problems is that the Maven Release plugin updates the version number first to the release version, then to the next SNAPSHOT version. By the time you're merging this into *master* as part of `git flow release finish`, the version number is the SNAPSHOT version.

See here for more info on some of these problems: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/maven-git-flow-plugin-for-better-releases/

There's an alternative Maven plugin that supposedly fixes many of the issues named above and in the blog post: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow